# Why textfield values are being cleared after button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

**qr.php**

```
 <form id="contactForm" class="forma" method="post">

      <h1 id="datah1">Your data</h1>
      <div class="formcontainer">
      <hr class="hr3"/>
      <div class="container">
        <label for="uname" id="fullnameofres"><strong>Full name of your restaurant</strong></label>
        <input  type="text" name="textfieldtest" id="user_value" placeholder="Full name of your business.." name="user_value" required>

        <label for="psw"><strong>Number of tables</strong></label>
        <input type="text" id="nr_tables" placeholder="How many tables you have..." name="nr_tables" required>

        <hr class="hr1">
        <div id="templatesDiv">

        <label for="psw"><strong>Template</strong></label>
        <button id="tmplt_btn" onclick="go_to_templates_grid()" style="margin-bottom: 15px">Click here for all templates </button>

        </div>
        <div> 
        You selected : <b> <span id="templateResult" name="templateResult"> </b>
        </div>        
        <hr class="hr2">
        <label for="psw"><strong>Do you have menu</strong></label>
        <!-- <input type="text" id="menu_choice" placeholder="Yes/No" name="menu_choice" required> -->
        <select name="menu_dropdown" id="menu_dropdown">
        <option value="None" selected disabled > Yes/No </option>
         <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
         <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="submitara" name="submit">Submit</button>   
    </form>
```

Expected behaviour: The user fills in the fields, after clicking on 'Click here for all templates', another php file being opened, user is choosing Template, back to **qr.php**, submit form and that's all.

The problem is that all data which was typed in text fields being cleared after clicking on 'Click here for all templates'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `type` for a `button` is submit, so when you click that button, you are submitting the form. Add: `type="button"` to the `button` code so that it will just run your function but not submit.

```
<button type="button" id="tmplt_btn" 
        onclick="go_to_templates_grid()" 
        style="margin-bottom: 15px">Click here for all templates </button>
```

Comment: Also consider event-preventing the button onclick behavior if changing the type is not possible

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!